# Sortable HTML table in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller

I want to add sorting to a HTML table populated by Hibernate. The actual sorting has to be done by a database. To feed "Order by" condition to the database Java has to match passed sort parameters to a column in a query. I'm unsure how to implement this matching.

I could pass something like "Employee.salary" but then this condition need to be checked like all parameters passed from client. This check would require getting column name from Hibernate annotations, and this is not easy I guess. Also, the column can be query-specific and not corresponding to a table field.

Another way is to use hardcoded values in a presentation layer. But this will tie presentation layer with a persistence layer, which is also not good I think.

How do you deal with server-side sorting in web applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have an `Employee` entity, then I want an `EmployeeRepository` that lets me `findEmployeesBySalary(SortType sortType, int skip, int limit)`

From the web service side, I want a URI like

```
foo.com/employees?by=salary&skip=10&limit=50
```

which returns something like (as a AJAX XHR call)

```
<employees>
    <employee uri="/employee/1" />
    <employee uri="/employee/2" />
    <employee uri="/employee/3" />
</employees>
```

or the full-blown HTML page rendered appropriate.

This conveniently allows caching of employees on the client side (which the cache size being flexible) and at the HTTP level.

Note that, column names? Irrelevant. You would have a `HiberateEmployeeRepository` that implements the `EmployeeRepository` interface as needed. Express this stuff as methods, and use complex parameters if you need to.

You could even have two separate methods if you want, rather than an enum, `findHighestPaidEmployees` and `findLowestPaidEmployees` - `foo.com/employees?salary=lowest&skip=10&take=30` mind you, that's a horribly depressing URI.

Comment: In my understanding SortType enum is a part of service layer API. So web controller must translate from URI parameters to a SortType enum

Comment: Yes, that, or if you have different methods, which method to call. When I use JAX-RS/Jersey I can have URI path or query parmaters marshalled to objects automatically via a constructor that takes a String, or a valueOf factory.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create some kind of an intermediate layer that maps the column names between the view and the tables. This way you can send extra parameters to your query in an encapsulated form, and in your server side code you can use them according to your actual query.
For sorting do sth like this:

```
public class ColumnMapping {
    String tableColName;
    String dbColName;
    //getters, setters, ctors and anything else required
}
List<ColumnMapping > orderColumns = new ArrayList<ColumnMapping >();
orderColumns.add(new ColumnMapping("foo", "bar"));

//... server side
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("select * from books ");
if(orderingApplicable) {
   queryString.appendd("order by ");
   queryString.append(implode(orderColumns, ", "));
}
```

Where implode is a theoretical function gluing the list elements with commas into a string.
Remarks:
You can easily pre-populate the view-db mapping on startup if immutable.
The same can be done for group by.
This is just a stub, but extensible to include aggregate functions or whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

You could sort data at the client side, with help various js tools. It will be minimize requests to database

Comment: I want to make it scalable, client-side sorting will not work for large data.

Comment: I think pagination and client side sorting is two conflicting technique. Pagination aims for reduced data transfer and need server side sorting, while client side sorting needs to transfer all data to client to do sorting